# Attempt to present ... on ... whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am trying to perform a segue to a "Success window" when a payment has been correctly processed. I am trying to do this by using the:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "successView", sender: self)
```

inside my addCardViewController function. (shown here:)

```
    func addCardViewController(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController, didCreateToken token: STPToken, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {

    // Monetary amounts on stripe are based on the lowest monetary unit (i.e. cents),
    // therefore, we need to multiply the dollar amount by 100 to get the correct amount.
    let stripeAmount = toPay * 100

    // Call the 'stripeCharge' Firebase cloud function, with user's card token and amount
    functions.httpsCallable("stripeCharge").call(["token": token.tokenId, "amount": String(stripeAmount)]) { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }

        // Get the charge id after successful payment
        var chargeId: String
        if let data = result?.data as? [String: Any] {
            chargeId = data["chargeId"] as? String ?? "no id"
            print("Charge id: \(chargeId)")

            //send new info

            //show successfull payment view with charge

            //self.present(self.successViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "successView", sender: self)
        }

        completion(nil)
        //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "successView", sender: self)
    }

}
```

but I keep getting the error "Attempt to present ... on ... whose view is not in the window hierarchy"

Anyone knows why this is? here is a picture of the main.storyboard
[here is a picture of the main.storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekq5f.png)

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you are not on the main thread? Usually the callback functions of network calls are off of the main thread. Unless you're sure that that's not the problem, try adding it:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "successView", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: the addCardViewController function happens inside a button press, when the button is pressed, the card view controller is displayed. being inside that new view controller I wanted to display the success view. but I keep getting the problem. I have attempted: dismissing the card view controller and then calling the "self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "successView", sender: self)" from the actual button press, and I tried using your code but still nothing. Thank you for the suggestion tho

Comment: So, is `self` your PayViewController? Whatever `self` is, it needs to be the top view controller (the visible one) when `self.performSegue` is called. If you're saying that the `addCardViewController` is presented on top of it, you need to either present from that view controller, or dismiss it before performing the segue. This could be `addCardViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "successView", sender: self) })`